# Lost network after update

Tags: internet

I am having a problem with lost internet connectivity after an update. I am getting the system network service are not compatible with this version.

I have done the research and found the fix of downloading, transferring to the broken laptop and then using terminal to install the deb files. These are:

- libnl-3-200_3.2.21-1_amd64.deb
- libnl-genl-3_200_3.2.21-1_amd64.deb
- libnl-route-3-200_3.2.21-1_amd64.deb

They all install then I reboot and I still don't have internet.

Any help with this would be appreciated.